# Infinite Loop stops working after 5 to 10 seconds

Tags: c++, qt, infinite-loop

Infinite Loop `(while (true))` stops working in a 5-10 sec. I use the Qt technology. Here's the code:

```
void Worker::start() {
    while (true) {
        QNetworkReply* reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("link")));
        QEventLoop loop;
        connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
        loop.exec();

        QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll());
        QJsonObject root = document.object();
        QJsonValue response = root.value("response");
        QJsonObject items = response.toObject().value("items").toArray().at(0).toObject();
        int comments = items.value("comments").toObject().value("count").toInt();

        if (comments == 0) {
            qDebug() << "Comment";
            QThread::sleep(3);
        }
        qDebug() << "END";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to see where it stops using debugger?

Comment: Yes I did. It looks like that works fine 5 to 10 times and then just stop working. Maybe `QNetworkReply` has some limitation.

Comment: But where exactly it stops? Like WhiteWind told you, use a debugger, wait for 10 seconds and then pause the application - then you see the location the program waits...

Comment: I've found the problem. Thank you guys. The API has a limitation for the requests. I've added Sleep in the end and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Please write an answer or delete the question, in order to get it out of the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from OPs comment (just to get this out of the list of unanswered questions):

The API has a limitation for the requests. I've added Sleep in the end and it works.